# What is the purpose of charset attribute of script element in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, character-encoding

In HTML, script element has optional charset attribute.

What is the purpose of it?

When is it useful?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your javascript files are encoded with a different encoding than the page is using, you can use the `charset` attribute to tell the browser how to interpret it.

For example, if the page is using `Latin1`, but the JS file was created with `UTF-8`.

Comment: Although it seems to me that it's better to put the encoding in the header of the response that returns the script.

Comment: @GolezTrol - It _would_ be better, but not all web authors have such control over the headers.

Comment: If the page is using some other encoding (in my case, euc-kr) and the JS is using UTF8, some text written by calling document.write() or setting innerHTML of some element will be correctly encoded in the encoding (euc-kr) not UTF8?

Comment: @JohnnyLim - If you don't identify the javascript encoding (either with an HTTP header or the charset attribute) in such a case, the browser will not read the javascript correctly.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, I meant if the charset of script is set as UTF8. Then does it work as I questioned?

Comment: @JohnnyLim - If you set the `charset` attribute correctly (meaning it matches the actual encoding of the js file), then yes, it will work correctly.

Comment: You mean some UTF8-encoded text in JS will be converted into the page encoding automatically, if I write it into the page, right?

Comment: @JohnnyLim - It won't get converted automatically. The browser will interpret it correctly.

Answer (score 5):

The purpose of the `charset` parameter is to specify the encoding of the external script in cases where the encoding is not specified at the HTTP protocol level. It is *not* meant to override encoding information in HTTP headers, and it does not do that.

This is useful when the author cannot control HTTP headers and the headers do not specify character encoding. It is also useful for offline files, such as in a local copy of a web page accessed directly, not via an HTTP server, so that no HTTP headers exist.

In practice, it is not very useful. If you need to use non-Ascii characters in a JavaScript file, you can use UTF-8 encoding. If you use UTF-8 with a leading BOM, the BOM acts as a useful indicator that lets browsers infer the encoding. But it does not hurt to additionally use `charset=utf-8`.

Comment: Are you sure that the charset specified in the header of an included JS file has more priority than the explicit charset specified in the main html page? Is this claim tested on real browsers **in the wild**?

Comment: Yes, tested in Firefox, Chrome, IE (Win 7). Test page: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/test/js/demo.html

Answer (score 3):

Each JavaScript file is a separate element from page, after all you can even load JS from some remote author's server that otherwise have no relations to your page at all. Just as with any other external element, you can manually specify "charset" if remote server returns wrong charset for some reason or just to be sure.

Also, if you have write access to this JS file yourself, you may want to replace all non-ASCII with Unicode position escapes - this will guarantee that symbols will always be interpreted correctly, no matter what encoding is specified in headers. Some JS minifiers, like Google Closure Compiler, can do it for you automatically.

Comment: So which takes priority? `script charset` or the header charset of the included js file?